# What are some conferences for publishing papers on Deep Learning for Human Activity recognition?

Tags: deep-learning, reference-request, research, human-activity-recognition

What are some conferences for publishing papers on Deep Learning for Human Activity recognition? Do any of the major conferences have specific tracks for Human Activity Recognition?

Answer (score 1):

If your using computer vision, the top recognised conference is CVPR (computer vision and pattern recognition).

You can also try to submit at ICML (International conference on machine learning) and NIPS (Neural Information Processing Systems), which focuses on applications of machine learning and deep learning.

I'd also recommend IJCAI (International joint conference on artificial intelligence).